# MVC Core Compare PagedList vs OrderBy Skip Take

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, pagination

There are two methods to create pages for lists in MVC Core. Eg, I have a list of 20 items, and want to display 5 items per page, like a shopping website.

What are the benefits/comparison of using one over the other, is there general industry practice? I am trying to understand, many different flavors of doing things, wanted to see if there is optimal method

1) There is the `OrderBy-Skip-Take` Method

```
public ViewResult List(int productpage = 1)
 => View(repository.Products
 .OrderBy(p => p.ProductID)
 .Skip((productpage - 1) * pagesize)
 .Take(pagesize));
```

2) Also the Nuget using `PagedList`

```
return View(_context.Product.ToPagedList(productpage, pagesize));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PagedList` is using `Skip` and `Take` internally too. If you look at the [`PagedList`](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) source in [github](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList) you will find something like this in the `PagedListExtensions` class:

```
if (superset.Count() < pageSize)
    yield return superset;
else
{
    var numberOfPages = Math.Ceiling(superset.Count() / (double)pageSize);
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfPages; i++)
        yield return superset.Skip(pageSize * i).Take(pageSize);                
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/PagedListExtensions.cs
And: http://www.extensionmethod.net/1882/csharp/queryover/topagedlist